# does anybody know any good opensource syslog reader tool?

Tags: syslog

I manage to send all my servers logs to a central syslog server. Now What?  How do i make sense of this avalanche of data?  does anybody know any good opensource syslog reader tool  or any paid ones such as sawmill?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out Sagan (http://sagan.io).  Basically,  it takes your logs as they come in and "detect" when bad things are happening.   Sagan works a lot like the Snort IDS engine,  but with logs instead of packets.   Things that are detected can then be forwarded to a GUI like Snorby,  Sguil, etc.

It's an open source project (GNU/GPLv2) and runs on *nix platforms.  More information can be found at:

http://sagan.io

Answer (score 0):

I know baretail, A free real-time log file monitoring tool

http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it, but heard good things about it:

http://www.ossec.net/

It's perhaps more than what you asked for, but your question doesn't make exactly clear what you are looking for in the logs.

For displaying of the logs on a GUI you could check LogAnalyzer (http://loganalyzer.adiscon.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Logstash](http://logstash.net/), [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/), and [kibana](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/) is a nice modern stack for analyzing logs.